# How to execute FB client on different Android devices?

Tags: java, android

I have a naive problem, but I confused: I have made application which uses Facebook SDK, and it works good on my device and emulator, and it doesn't work on customer's device. He doesn't get any error or exceptions - when he press button for authorize he will see "loading" message, but progress bar will be closed, and authorization will be canceled. What problem is it? Thank you for anything hints

```
    private void submitExec() {

/*      if (SQLiteDbWrapper.getInstance().getBookCount()==0) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "A list of books is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }*/

        SQLiteDbWrapper.getInstance().makeFacebook(this, this.getApplicationContext());
        if (SQLiteDbWrapper.getInstance().getConnector().getFacebook().isSessionValid()) {
            //new SubmitClass().execute();
        }
        else {

            SessionEvents.AuthListener listener = new SessionEvents.AuthListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAuthSucceed() {
                    //MyBookDroidActivity.this.executeSubmitClass();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAuthFail(String error) {

                }
            };
            SessionEvents.addAuthListener(listener);
            SQLiteDbWrapper.getInstance().getConnector().login();
        }
    }
```

It is function for authorizating.

```
public void makeFacebook(Activity activity, Context context) {

    if (mConnector==null||!mConnector.getFacebook().isSessionValid()) {
        mConnector=new FacebookConnector(FACEBOOK_APPID, activity, context, 
        new String[] {"publish_stream", "read_stream", "email"});
    }
}
```

It is function for making FacebookConnector.

Comment: You'll need to run some kind of LogCat on that specific phone to supply more information or your question will go unanswered. Also, I would suggest running your app on many different SDKs in the emulator.

Comment: Have added a code, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding logging:

```
public void appendLog(String text)
{       
   File logFile = new File("sdcard/log.file");
   if (!logFile.exists())
   {
      try
      {
         logFile.createNewFile();
      } 
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   try
   {
      //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
      BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
      buf.append(text);
      buf.newLine();
      buf.close();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

If you can't run some kind of LogCat or collect the stacktrace on the device yourself, you may want to look into:
http://code.google.com/p/microlog4android/